# How to join three tables in SQL Server 2012 and calculate ranking based on 2 attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables:

**tblEmployee**

```
E_ID    E_Name  E_City
--------------------------------
101     sasa    Mumbai
102     sdf     California
103     trt     Illinois
104     dssd    Texas
105     trt     Pennsylvania
106     wee     Arizona
107     rer     Texas
108     wqe     California
109     sadd    Michigan
```

**tblGen**

`Tgenerate` is boolean value

```
  Emp_ID    Tgenerate
  --------------------
    105     1
    108     1
    102     1
    102     1
    102     0
    104     1
    107     0
    108     1
    109     0
```

And the **tblStat**:

```
Emp_ID  Status
------------------
103     Pending
107     Pending
103     Pending
101     Delivered
104     Pending
104     Pending
108     Pending
101     Delivered
105     Delivered
```

I have to join these 3 tables and want output like this

```
E_Name  EmployeeID  City    TgenerateCount  Delivered_Count     Ranking
```

`TgenerateCount` is calculated for every employee. It is count of `TgenerateCount` having value 1, for ex 102 has 2 TgenerateCount and 109 has 0 TgenerateCount.

Delivered_Count is count of Status of those who has 'Delivered' status. For ex. 101 has 2 Delivered. I want to display every user in the output table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So how is the ranking decided?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ranking will be decided on the basis of 2 attributes employee who have more DeliveredCount and more TgenerateCount.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I am storing the Count results in temporary table by creating one but unable to get result.

Comment: @Eric I tried to calculate my rankings by doing below:-SELECT TG.EMPCODE, 
Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY TS.COUNT_DEL DESC, TG.COUNT_TG DESC) AS YOUR_RANK
FROM
(SELECT EmpCode, SUM(CASE WHEN Tgenerate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_TG FROM TBLTGENERATE1 GROUP BY EMPCODE) TG
INNER JOIN
(SELECT EMP_CODE, SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_DEL FROM TBLSTAT GROUP BY EMP_CODE) TS
ON TG.EMPCODE = TS.EMP_CODE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your two fact tables have a many:1 relationship with your dimension table, you should aggregate them before joining them.

```
SELECT
  e.*,
  COALESCE(g.rows, 0)     AS TgenerateCount,
  COALESCE(s.rows, 0)     AS DeliveredCount,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(g.rows, 0) + COALESCE(s.rows,0) DESC)   AS ranking
FROM
  tblEmployee     e
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT E_ID, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM tblGen WHERE Tgenerate = 1 GROUP BY E_ID
)
  g
    ON g.E_ID = e.E_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT E_ID, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM tblStat WHERE STATUS = 'Delivered' GROUP BY E_ID
)
  s
    ON s.E_ID = e.E_ID
```

You've been unclear on how the ranking should be completed, so this simply gives an example ranking.

Comment: can you help me to calculate ranking based on the attribute DeliveryCount and TgenerateCount. Ranking would be such that If Tgenerate count is 5( fox e.g.) and delivered count is 3.He should be ranked first, Even if other user has Tgenerate count more than 5.

Comment: @rchau change the `,` to a `+` inside the ORDER BY clause and add `DESC` before the final closing `)` on that line.